# Linux grep and print between special character

Tags: linux, text, grep

So this is how my data looks.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
date        start     stop      durat  cond  acc_5  acc_6  dialled_number   outg_trunk  connected_num    inc_trunk   calling_num      charged_num      ring  que
60512-09-56  66:65:99  66:90:65  0081212  NI                  90000                        912690            0050060055  56012975125        56012975125        8     0
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
date        start     stop      durat  cond  acc_5  acc_6  dialled_number   outg_trunk  connected_num    inc_trunk   calling_num      charged_num      ring  que
60512-09-56  66:67:59  66:95:55  00955  I                   900012                        9120512            0700050005  901299120512        901299120512        0     0
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
date        start     stop      durat  cond  acc_5  acc_6  dialled_number   outg_trunk  connected_num    inc_trunk   calling_num      charged_num      ring  que
60512-09-56  66:67:60  66:95:55  009512  NJ                  90009            5000060069  05055                        9120512            912999            5     0

endpoint                endp_type     codec_5     codec_6     cum_pack_lost  pack_lost  frac_lost   mean_delay  worst_delay  mean_jitter  worst_jitter  R-value
50.9.0.56:57696         a_multiLim    PCMA                    0              0          0          0           65           0            0             996
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  ------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is just an example of the data, it contains thousands of these lines. And i want to find the data containing for example "900012"

So i get

---

```
date        start     stop      durat  cond  acc_5  acc_6  dialled_number   outg_trunk  connected_num    inc_trunk   calling_num      charged_num      ring  que
60512-09-56  66:65:99  66:90:65  0081212  NI                  90000                        912690            0050060055  56012975125        56012975125        8     0
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I know i could do "cat file.txt | grep 900012 -A1 -B1" but some lines are more then 1 above and one under. so is there a way to tell grep to print the rows until it hits "-----" above and under then stop.

I could do this simply in python or bash. But iam looking for a one line thing that i can just paste in bash, since i would use this in hundreds of systems. And dont want to copy paste a file etc in to every system.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a way with `awk`:

```
awk '/^--/ { if (f) {print line} {f=0; line=""; next}}
     /900012/ {f=1}
     {if (line) {line=line RS $0} else {line=$0}}' file
```

#### Explanation

- `/^--/ { if (f) {print line} {f=0; line=""; next}}` in lines starting with `--`, it checks if the flag `f` is set or not. If so, prints the buffered data. Then it unsets `f`, empties the buffered line and jumps to the next line.
- `/900012/ {f=1}` if the line matches `900012`, then trigger the flag `f`.
- `{if (line) {line=line RS $0} else {line=$0}}` at any line, buffer the content in the variable `line`.

For your sample input it returns:

```
$ awk '/^--/ { if (f) {print line} {f=0; line=""; next}} /900012/ {f=1} {if (line) {line=line RS $0} else {line=$0}}' file
date        start     stop      durat  cond  acc_5  acc_6  dialled_number   outg_trunk  connected_num    inc_trunk   calling_num      charged_num      ring  que
60512-09-56  66:67:59  66:95:55  00955  I                   900012                        9120512            0700050005  901299120512        901299120512        0     0
```